# Are counters garbage collected?

Tags: garbage-collection, erlang, counter

In the [counters](http://erlang.org/doc/man/counters.html) documentation I don't see any option to free a counter array. Can I assume they will be garbage collected or cleaned in some other way without my action?

Comment: From `new` docs: "Counters are not tied to the current process and are automatically garbage collected when they are no longer referenced."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://erlang.org/doc/man/counters.html#new-2) they will be garbage collected as soon as no more process will reference them:

> Counters are not tied to the current process and are automatically garbage collected when they are no longer referenced.

Comment: yeah, didn't expect it in the `new` section